# Getting Web Element Using VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I can't seem to return the web element using this function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function scrape2(id As String)

Set objhttp1 = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim doc1 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
objhttp1.Open "GET", "https://www.axie.tech/axie-pricing/" & id, True
objhttp1.send

Set doc1 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
doc1.body.innerHTML = objhttp1.responseText

Set Result = doc1.FindElementByClass("axie-pricing_decodedGenesCapsule__m9R-C")

scrape2 = doc1.Text
    
End Function
```

Function Input: 373595

Expected Result:

```
D
R1
R2
Telescope
Telescope
Sleepless
Sakura
Pink Cheek
Curly
Anemone
Sponge
Blue Moon
Piranha
Piranha
Lam
Lagging
Scaly Spear
Teal Shell
Koi
Nimo
Snake Jar
```

Comment: `scrape2 = result.Text` ?  What result are you getting?

Comment: You not going to get the information from that URL directly, it's all generated via script and XHR. Check from the network and replicate the XHR request for its JSON data.

Comment: Try making the call synchronous by changing the last parameter in the open call to False. `objhttp1.Open "GET", "https://www.axie.tech/axie-pricing/" & id, False`

Answer (score 1):

`doc1` is an `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` instance which does not have a `FindElementByClass` method. Nor a `.text` property of any nodes within the DOM. The method you are referencing is one from `Selenium Type` class where you have an instance of `WebDriver`.

Then there a variety of other issues. What you see on the page is dynamically rendered, and the data you want comes from XHR POST requests using graphql queries that return JSON. You would need to formulate those requests and use a JSON parser, such as in my example below, on the results.

Also, use `Option Explicit`, declare all your variables, use meaningful names and make the request synchronous by passing `False` in the `.Open`  line.

`parts` is a collection of dictionaries you need to `For Each` over, then `For Each Key`, where `Key` is variant, over the `.Keys` of each dictionary.
Select the items you want. The key `abilities` returns a collection, so needs to be handled differently if used.

**TODO:**

1. `R1` and `R2` you need to use the parent ids and extract from requests for those ids info. The code below is for the child id and returns column `D` of your desired results.
2. `data` requests a lot more info that it seems you need so you could remove a lot of the parameters within it.

---

**JSON library:**

I use `JsonConverter.bas`. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called `JsonConverter` . Remove the top `Attribute ....` line from the copied code and `Option Explicit` if already specified.

You then need to go:

`VBE > Tools > References` > Add references to:

```
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 Library (or your version).
```

In VBA for JSON the `[]` denotes a collection and the `{}` represents a dictionary.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintGetAxieDetail()

    Dim response As Object
    
    Set response = GetAxieGeneDetail("5016162")
    
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(response)
    
End Sub

Public Function GetAxieGeneDetail(ByVal id As String) As Object
    
    Dim http As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim doc1 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim data As String
    
    Set http = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set doc1 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With http
    
        .Open "POST", "https://axieinfinity.com/graphql-server-v2/graphql", False
        
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "referer", "https://www.axie.tech/"
        .setRequestHeader "accept-language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"

        data = "{""operationName"":""GetAxieDetail"",""variables"":{""axieId"":""" & id & """},""query"":""query GetAxieDetail($axieId: ID!)" & _
                "{\n  axie(axieId: $axieId) {\n    ...AxieDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AxieDetail on Axie {\n  id\n  image" & _
                "\n  class\n  chain\n  name\n  genes\n  owner\n  birthDate\n  bodyShape\n  class\n  sireId\n  sireClass\n  matronId\n  matronClass" & _
                "\n  stage\n  title\n  breedCount\n  level\n  figure {\n    atlas\n    model\n    image\n    __typename\n  }" & _
                "\n  parts {\n    ...AxiePart\n    __typename\n  }\n  stats {\n    ...AxieStats\n    __typename\n  }" & _
                "\n  auction {\n    ...AxieAuction\n    __typename\n  }\n  ownerProfile {\n    name\n    __typename\n  }" & _
                "\n  battleInfo {\n    ...AxieBattleInfo\n    __typename\n  }" & _
                "\n  children {\n    id\n    name\n    class\n    image\n    title\n    stage\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename" & _
                "\n}\n\nfragment AxieBattleInfo on AxieBattleInfo {\n  banned\n  banUntil\n  level\n  __typename" & _
                "\n}\n\nfragment AxiePart on AxiePart {\n  id\n  name\n  class\n  type\n  specialGenes\n  stage\n  abilities" & _
                "{\n    ...AxieCardAbility\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AxieCardAbility on AxieCardAbility" & _
                "{\n  id\n  name\n  attack\n  defense\n  energy\n  description\n  backgroundUrl\n  effectIconUrl\n  __typename\n}" & _
                "\n\nfragment AxieStats on AxieStats {\n  hp\n  speed\n  skill\n  morale\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AxieAuction on Auction" & _
                "{\n  startingPrice\n  endingPrice\n  startingTimestamp\n  endingTimestamp\n  duration\n  timeLeft\n  currentPrice" & _
                "\n  currentPriceUSD\n  suggestedPrice\n  seller\n  listingIndex\n  state\n  __typename\n}\n""}"

        .send data
        
        Dim axieDetail As Object, geneResults As Object
        
        Set axieDetail = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        Set geneResults = axieDetail("data")("axie")("parts") 'this returns a collection to For Each over
        Set GetAxieGeneDetail = geneResults
        
    End With
    
End Function
```

---

**Sample of JSON:**

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing what JSON parser is that in the screenshot?

Comment: @RaymondWu It is not a great json  viewer IMO but sometimes handles string formatting that a lot of other viewers reject. The one shown is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ but for a selection see: https://geekflare.com/json-online-tools/ and choose ones that suit your needs. I typically use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ , and have the one in the screenshot for difficult cases, but have seen some on the list from geekflare I like the look of.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the recommendation, I have been using one off googling ages ago and visually it is very simple so I will definitely try those out!

Comment: Yeah, as a minimum I think you want one that allows for import/export, validation/error flagging, text search and tree view. @RaymondWu